# Why do require to change code runtime?

Tags: functional-programming, runtime, programming-languages

I found many languages provides some way to change code runtime. Many people ask queries regarding how to change code in this or that language runtime. Here I mean by change code is that rewrite code itself at runtime by using reflection or something else.

I have around 6 year of experience in Java application development. I never come again any problem where I have to change code at time.

Can anyone explain why we require to change code at runtime?

Comment: You never used a *strategy* pattern before?

Comment: Furthermore I don't get what this has to do with functional programming. Functional programming is *not* about changing code at runtime.

Comment: Here I mean by change code is that rewrite code at runtime by using reflection or something else.

Comment: What about [plug-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) ??

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced three huge benefits of changing code at runtime:

1. Fixing bugs in a production environment without shutting down the application server. This allowed us to fix bugs on just some part of the application without interrupting the whole system.
2. Possibility of changing the business rule without having to deploy a new version of the application. A quicker deploy of features.
3. Writing unit test is easier. For example, you can mock dependencies, add some desired behaviour to some objects and etc. [Spock Framework](http://spockframework.org) does well this.

Of course, we had this benefits because we have a very well defined development process on how to proceed on this situations.

Answer (score 1):

At times you may need to call a method based on the input, that was received earlier in the program.

It could be used for dynamic calculation of value based on the key index, where every key is calculated in a different way or calculation requires fetching required data from different sources. Instead of using switch statement you can invoke a method dynamically using methodName+indexOfTheKey.